# Problem with $<$ and $>$ symbols

Tags: equations, symbols, babel

This is the main error

> Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }.\par \end{align}

I realised the problem is with the symbols `<` and `>`. On Overleaf, I with the same structure and the same files I don't have any problem with those symbols.

MNWE (on my PC. On Overleaf, they both work as usual.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    1 = 2_{<}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, openany]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    1 = 2_{<}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

FULL LOG

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.7)  7 MAY 2021 15:38
entering extended mode
**./Mainc.tex
(Mainc.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\bk12.clo
File: bk12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@chapter=\count180
\c@section=\count181
\c@subsection=\count182
\c@subsubsection=\count183
\c@paragraph=\count184
\c@subparagraph=\count185
\c@figure=\count186
\c@table=\count187
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks15
\inpenc@posthook=\toks16
)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.sty
Package: babel 2021/04/26 3.58 The Babel package

(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\babel.def
File: babel.def 2021/04/26 3.58 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count188
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@unhyphenated=\language83

(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/babel\txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count189

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/babel-spanish\spanish.ldf
Language: spanish.ldf 2016/03/03 v5.0p Spanish support from the babel system
\es@quottoks=\toks17
\es@quotdepth=\count190
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 561.
Package babel Info: Making . an active character on input line 662.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 707.
Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 707.
))
(D:\Programas\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count191
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (Mainc.aux)
\openout1 = `Mainc.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 9.

! Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg< was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }
                 
l.10    1 = 2_{<}
               
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! You can't use `\eqno' in vertical mode.
\endequation ->\eqno 
                     \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue 
l.11 \end{equation}
                   
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 \end{equation}
                   
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
l.11 \end{equation}
                   
The `$' that I just saw supposedly matches a previous `$$'.
So I shall assume that you typed `$$' both times.

[1{C:/Users/marco/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

]
(Mainc.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 8.
) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1826 strings out of 479287
 25268 string characters out of 2865244
 326838 words of memory out of 3000000
 19348 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 407751 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,4n,54p,166b,361s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 <C:\Users\marco\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/dpi600
\ecrm1200.pk><D:/Programas/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>

Output written on Mainc.pdf (1 page, 10342 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

---

Also, I have updated the packages from MikTeX these days and is the only cause I can imagine.

I know I can use \text{less} for < even in mathmode, but I would like to get it work normally.. I'm at your disposition for any information I haven't provided.

PD: Why doesn't Matjax works here?

Comment: Tip: If the two problems are not related then focus the question on one problem at a time.

Comment: I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I said that they both work on Overleaf but on my PC (using Texmaker) the MNWE doesn't works while the MWE works. Ok, I will erase the second problem. I just thought it could had information, but I guess they are too unrealated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest to open an issue at the babel github. It seems to have changed the shorthand handling. https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues

Comment: for your comment on mathjax it is not enabled here as it would be confusing as it doesn't use tex, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I have no idea what 'shorthand handling' means but I will open an issue on the link you provided. Is it possible to get an older version of the babel package or it doesn't works that way? Yesterday it all worked fine, so I'm guessing updating packages made babel update as well.

Comment: if you don't need or use the spanish shorthands you can do `\shorthandoff{<}` after begin document.

Comment: I don't think I do; I've done it and now it works fine without other errors caming out from that. Thank you very much, you saved my day. Regarding the issue notification, which I've never done, should/could I link this question on it?

Comment: Another possible approach, if you can’t disable shorthands: `\textnormal{\textless}`. Or you could declare a synonym `\altlt` from the math alphabet.

Comment: `spanish` babel has quite a bit of problems left... Difficult to solve. See also https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/38 and https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/39. I always use `\usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}`... And the use utf-8 everywhere.

Comment: @Rmano, I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you use the option `es-noquoting` when using spanish babel:

```
\usepackage[spanish, es-noquoting]{babel}
```

The shorthands `>` and `<` cause trouble with many packages (such as ifthen or tikz).

You can use the environment `quoting` if you want to quote sentences according to the spanish rules (check pag 12-13 in the [spanish bibtex manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf))